# Pacakge installled succesfully but unable to import

Tags: installation, package-management, python

I installed a python package libxmlsec1 using sudo spt-get install libxmlsec1. I got the installation to be successful but when I try to import it in the python command line iam getting an import error. Please help me in sortin out the error.

Comment: Please add the error message that you got to your question.

Comment: It's not a Python package, so you can't import it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need dev version of the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmlsec1-dev
```